# VS Code - Oracle: Language Not Supported or Defined

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, plsql

I've been working work Oracle in the SQL Developer for a few days now and wanted to see if I can start working instead in VS Code.

I installed the extension: Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL).

I established a connection to my Oracle Database.

I put in a simple SELECT statement into a file.

I made sure 'Oracle-SQL and PLSQL' is selected on the bottom as the language, that Oracle is listed, and the connection is established to the database.

However, when I select RUN, it says: "Language not support or defined."

When I select the Oracle-SQL language, it appears to have a 'text' icon next to it.  I don't know if that means anything, but it appears to me something is missing.

What am I missing here?  This is my first time run, so it has never worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, you execute SQL by using "Execute SQL" or "Execute All" from the menu. (There's also toolbar icons available). It may be easier to associate the SQL file with the extension and your connection by right clicking on the connection in Oracle Explorer and choosing "Open Existing SQL File". Also, if you set the connection in Oracle Explorer to "Default" (again, right click in the connection node), every time you open a SQL file it will use that connection.

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO buttons on top the top of Visual Studio Code.

One is marked 'Run Code' and the other is 'Execute SQL'...

Ignore the 'Run Code' and select 'Execute SQL' instead...  then it will work.

Also,  Ensure that you have the necessary Oracle client software installed on your machine and that it is configured correctly. The "Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL)" extension relies on the Oracle client to connect to the database.